# How do I know if my `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is actually running in parallel?

Tags: python

I am trying to parallelize a for loop that appends to a list using Python using the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` class. My code works, but I'm not sure if it's actually *doing* multithreading. According to Python's documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), the `.map(func, iterable)` method of `Executor` instances should call the function over each element of the iterable in a somewhat arbitrary order:

```
map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)

Similar to map(func, *iterables) except:

  - the iterables are collected immediately rather than lazily;

  - func is executed asynchronously and several calls to func may
    be made concurrently.
```

But the output of my code appears in the same order as the iterable, which makes me think it isn't actually running in parallel:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import itertools


def foo(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return f"{x} + {y} = {x + y}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 8
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as e:
        prod = itertools.product(range(0, n), range(n, 2 * n))
        lst = list(e.map(foo, prod))
    assert len(lst) == n * n  # make sure we got them all
    print(lst)
```

The output is

```
> python main.py
['0 + 8 = 8', '0 + 9 = 9', '0 + 10 = 10', '0 + 11 = 11', '0 + 12 = 12', '0 + 13 = 13', '0 + 14 = 14', '0 + 15 = 15', '1 + 8 = 9', '1 + 9 = 10', '1 + 10 = 11', '1 + 11 = 12', '1 + 12 = 13', '1 + 13 = 14', '1 + 14 = 15', '1 + 15 = 16', '2 + 8 = 10', '2 + 9 = 11', '2 + 10 = 12', '2 + 11 = 13', '2 + 12 = 14', '2 + 13 = 15', '2 + 14 = 16', '2 + 15 = 17', '3 + 8 = 11', '3 + 9 = 12', '3 + 10 = 13', '3 + 11 = 14', '3 + 12 = 15', '3 + 13 = 16', '3 + 14 = 17', '3 + 15 = 18', '4 + 8 = 12', '4 + 9 = 13', '4 + 10 = 14', '4 + 11 = 15', '4 + 12 = 16', '4 + 13 = 17', '4 + 14 = 18', '4 + 15 = 19', '5 + 8 = 13', '5 + 9 = 14', '5 + 10 = 15', '5 + 11 = 16', '5 + 12 = 17', '5 + 13 = 18', '5 + 14 = 19', '5 + 15 = 20', '6 + 8 = 14', '6 + 9 = 15', '6 + 10 = 16', '6 + 11 = 17', '6 + 12 = 18', '6 + 13 = 19', '6 + 14 = 20', '6 + 15 = 21', '7 + 8 = 15', '7 + 9 = 16', '7 + 10 = 17', '7 + 11 = 18', '7 + 12 = 19', '7 + 13 = 20', '7 + 14 = 21', '7 + 15 = 22']
```

which is ordered exactly the same way as the product iterator.

Compare, for instance, the following Julia code:

```
using Base.Threads

foo(x, y)::String = "$x + $y = $(x + y)"

function main()
    vec = String[]
    n = 8
    tuples = Iterators.product(1:n, n+1:2n) |> collect
    @threads for (x, y) in tuples
        push!(vec, foo(x, y))
    end
    @assert length(vec) == n * n
    display(vec)
end

main()
```

The output is not in the same order as the iterator, which implies that
the code was executed in parallel—which is what I want:

```
> julia --threads=auto main.jl
64-element Vector{String}:
 "1 + 9 = 10"
 "2 + 9 = 11"
 "3 + 9 = 12"
 "4 + 9 = 13"
 "5 + 9 = 14"
 "6 + 9 = 15"
 "3 + 13 = 16"
 "4 + 13 = 17"
 "5 + 13 = 18"
 "6 + 13 = 19"
 "7 + 13 = 20"
 "5 + 10 = 15"
 "6 + 10 = 16"
 "7 + 10 = 17"
 "8 + 10 = 18"
 "1 + 11 = 12"
 "2 + 11 = 13"
 "5 + 14 = 19"
 "6 + 14 = 20"
...
```

### Questions

- How do can I tell if my Python code is actually running in parallel?
- If it isn't, how can I make it so?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-do-i-use-threading-in-python) shows how to obtain similar behavior to Julia's `@threads` using `multiprocessing.dummy import Pool`, but I am trying to learn the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` class, hence the new question.

Comment: By "parallel", do you mean "using more than one CPU core simultaneously"?

Comment: Yes, e.g. by spawning new threads or child processes.

Comment: Because your description sounds more like "concurrently" which can be achieved also by interleaved execution on a single core.

Comment: I welcome an edit to improve terminology. I think the Julia code I provided suffices as an unambiguous, working example of my desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python threading for anything else than io bound tasks is generally not a great idea...

Official documentation for the threading module says:

> In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation)... However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

As your function contains no IO, the input data will be process serially. So it is no surprise that you get your results in order...

Nor for your questions:

*How do can I tell if my Python code is actually running in parallel?*

Your code cannot run concurrently because of the GIL

*If it isn't, how can I make it so?*

You cannot use Python threads for concurrent execution on CPU bounded tasks. You could use processes instead of threads, but for such simple tasks, the overhead of process switching and data exchange is likely to decrease performances...

---

BTW, the linked answer using the threading module or multiprocessing.dummy, would suffer the same GIL problem and give the same result

Comment: The same behavior occurs when I use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead, which (according to the documentation) is supposed to "sidestep" the GIL.

Comment: It *can* run concurrently, but not in parallel, due to the GIL.

Comment: For `ProcessPoolExecutor`, The overhead required in python to multiprocess such a simple task will take significantly longer than the task itself. It's making/submitting tasks to the pool one by one, but each task is finished in the process before the next task is even created, so your order will always remain consistent.